# Limit of sequence $a_n = \ln(n^3-3n^2)-\ln(en^3+2n+7)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Calculate the limit of the sequence given by:

$$a_n=\ln(n^3 -3n^2)-\ln(en^3+2n+7)$$

If you can provide theorem and conditions , that'd be great.

My teacher assigned this for handin work, but the book and lecture had nothing in information of $\ln$. I'm very lost.

Comment: thank you for editing my post , how to type equation like that ?

Comment: For some basic information about writing maths at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latexhelp/notation).

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$\frac{n^3 -3n^2}{en^3+2n+7} = \frac{1 -\dfrac3{n}}{e+\dfrac2{n^2}+\dfrac7{n^3}} \to \frac1e.$$

Comment: As simple and short as that. +1

Answer (score 1):

The symbol $\ln$, or $\log$, stands for the [natural logarithm](http://enwp.org/natural_logarithm). I will stick to $\log$ for this answer.

It is the inverse of the exponential function (so $\log a = x$ precisely when $a = e^x$), and the indefinite integral of $\frac 1x$:

$$\log x = \int_1^x \frac1\xi \,\mathrm d\xi$$

A property of $\log$ that will be of use to you in solving your question is that:

$$\log xy = \log x + \log y$$

from which we derive:

$$\log\frac xy = \log x - \log y$$

A last thing that you will need to evaluate the limit is that $\log$ is *continuous* (see [here](http://enwp.org/continuous_function) for an introduction). That is to say, $\log$ "commutes" with limits:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \log(f(n)) = \log \left(\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)\right)$$

Hopefully, this is enough to get you started. Please add a comment if something is unclear to you.

Comment: thank you! this cleared alot of things for me , i will try to solve it now